# iPhone/iPad itunes library read access?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I looked thru the documentation a bit but didn't see anything of much substance (but I must not be looking in the right place)

What are my options if I want to iterate through a user's itunes library meta data?

Let's say I want to build an Array of all their song titles. Is this possible with current public SDK APIs?

Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) and [MPMediaQuery](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaQuery) classes, both are available in 3.0.

If you just want to get an array of all songs in the user's library, try this:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[[MPMediaQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *items = [query items];
```